# Create Umbraco Member using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, umbraco

I'm trying to create an Umbraco Member using a SQL Server stored procedure instead of the GUI.

Using the SQL Server Profiler I can see that there is a function I can use:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [cmsMember] ([nodeId],[Email],[LoginName],[Password]) VALUES (@0,@1,@2,@3)',
                   N'@0 int,@1 nvarchar(4000),@2 nvarchar(4000),@3 nvarchar(4000)',
                   @0=1052, @1=N'test2@email.nl', @2=N'Test2',
                   @3=N'HMMB0498bIiVQ+EoO3ywJQ==6TdcRwNTt/MqaxS1O/ZiQ3906Vd3GcVfgiNHGFWBiTw='
```

Except the nodeId is not unique. Because a member is linked to a node.

I already created a stored procedure to create an Umbraco user and it just needed 2 inserts queries. But it seems like that an Umbraco member needs 10 inserts.

Is it even possible to create a member this way?

Comment: Please don't. Use the API.https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Management/Services/MemberService

Comment: Here's a good tutorial with an easy way to create a member registration page: http://siempresolutions.co.uk/blog/Umbraco_Members_Protected_Area_of_Website

Answer (score 0):

You should never try to connect to an Umbraco database directly as it might have some unexapected quircks. Each version makes the database more stable and less error prone. But to be sure you are are not messing up things, it is highly recommened to use the "Services" in Umbraco. These services can be injected in Umbraco and can store (and retrieve) directly from the database.

To use them, just inject the [IMemberService into your class](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/management/services/memberservice/).

```
public class MyClass
{
    private IMemberService _memberService;
    
    public MyClass(IMemberService memberService)
    {
        _memberService = memberService;
    }
}
```